# Flutter ListView.builder is overflowing the surrounding Container

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView.builder which is contained within a container. The scrolling is within the Container as wanted. But the ListView background appears to be flowing outside the container to the size of the elements. For example the screenshot has 5 elements. 4 & 5 are viewable by scrolling down in the white container. But you can see the white box which is expanded to the size of the 5 elements.

Hopefully I am missing something obvious.

[image]

```
class PlayerScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String quizId;

  const PlayerScreen({super.key, required this.quizId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CommonAppBar(
        showAlert: false,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 40,
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(
                  kBlueColor,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(150),
                ),
              ),
              child: QuizLeaderboard(quizId: quizId),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 60,
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class QuizLeaderboard extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String quizId;

  const QuizLeaderboard({super.key, required this.quizId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final quizPlayers = ref.watch(quizPlayersProvider(quizId));

    Widget leaderboardIcon(int index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        return const Icon(
          Icons.workspace_premium,
          size: 30,
          color: Color(kGoldColor),
        );
      }
      if (index == 1) {
        return const Icon(
          Icons.workspace_premium,
          size: 30,
          color: Color(kSilverColor),
        );
      }
      if (index == 2) {
        return const Icon(
          Icons.workspace_premium,
          size: 30,
          color: Color(kBronzeColor),
        );
      }
      return Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(kGreyBackgroundColor),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 8.0,
              bottom: 8,
              left: 10,
              right: 10,
            ),
            child: Text(
              (index + 1).toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ));
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        const Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: Text(
            'Leaderboard',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 75,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 70,
              right: 70,
            ),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              child: quizPlayers.when(
                  data: (quizPlayersList) => ListView.builder(
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: quizPlayersList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            tileColor: Colors.white,
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Color(
                                  quizPlayersList[index].player.appAvatarColor),
                              backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                quizPlayersList[index].player.appAvatar,
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              quizPlayersList[index].player.appDisplayName,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              '${quizPlayersList[index].score} points',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black54,
                              ),
                            ),
                            trailing: leaderboardIcon(index),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                  error: (error, stacktrace) {
                    print(error.toString());
                    return Text(
                      error.toString(),
                    );
                  },
                  loading: () => const LoadingSpinner()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 15,
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried wrapping with Expanded & Flexible, but no luck.

Comment: if you add background color to the scaffold, is it works?

Comment: Try wrapping the Column with Expanded, not the children of Column.

Comment: ok apologies, it is the tileColor: Colors.white property of ListTile which caused it. When I remove that then the white box disappears.

Comment: Try adding `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` to the container which has kBlueColor

Comment: try wrapping ListView with Material widget..